# what does "vt" do in linux agetty command parm

Tags: linux

using "man agetty" in Linux terminal

we can see " /sbin/agetty --local-line 9600 ttyS1 vt100 "
so what is this vt100 mean?

thank you guys.

so plz someone tell me what is this vt thing?  and what is the 100 doing ?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=8&topic=getty :

> term is the value to be used for the TERM  environment  variable. This overrides whatever init(8) may have set, and is inherited by login and the shell. The default is 'vt100', or 'linux' for Linux on a virtual terminal, or 'hurd' for GNU Hurd on a virtual terminal.

So the value of TERM determines what terminal emulation your systems uses to display the screen. In Linux default is "vt100" or "linux".

The name "vt100" comes from the first digital video terminal VT100 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100.